# Es mejor ejecutar una función en el código o en la base datos con TSQL

Tags: java, sql, optimización, tsql

Para obtener un cierto valor tengo que recurrir a una tabla de aforo en mi servidor SQL Server, donde por medio de una interpolación lineal obtengo dicho valor. Esta función de interpolación lineal la puedo incluir en mi código JAVA o por medio de TSQL recurrir a ella, mi duda es cual es el procedimiento óptimo; si asignar esta función a mi código o usar TSQL.

Script TSQL:

```html
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[LinInterpol](@AlturaAgua varchar, @Tanque varchar)
RETURNS float 
AS 
BEGIN

 DECLARE @actalt FLOAT = (SELECT CAST(@AlturaAgua AS FLOAT));
    DECLARE @postalt FLOAT = (SELECT CEILING(CAST (@AlturaAgua AS FLOAT)));
    DECLARE @prealt FLOAT = (SELECT CEILING(CAST (@AlturaAgua AS FLOAT)-1));
    DECLARE @postvol FLOAT = (SELECT CAST ((SELECT volumen FROM aforo_tanque WHERE altura=@postalt AND tanque=@Tanque) AS FLOAT));
    DECLARE @prevol FLOAT = (SELECT CAST ((SELECT volumen FROM aforo_tanque WHERE altura=@prealt AND tanque=@Tanque) AS FLOAT));
    DECLARE @actvol FLOAT;
    
    set @actvol = ((@actalt - @prealt)*(@postvol - @prevol)/(@postalt - @prealt))+@prevol;
    
    RETURN @actvol;
END;
```

Comment: ¿Óptimo desde que punto de vista? ¿Tiempo de desarrollo?¿Portabilidad? ¿Tiempo de ejecución? ¿Uso de recursos (memoria, cpu, IO)? Por otro lado, ¿cuál es el escenario de uso? Podrías aclararlo. Muchas gracias!

Comment: me refiero al uso de recursos

Comment: ¿Alguno en particular? Nuevamente, ¿cuál es el escenario de uso?

Comment: Por ejemplo, ¿cuántos usuarios van a ejecutar el programa al mismo tiempo? ¿El programa en java, es una web, una aplicación cliente con interfaz gráfica o una aplicación de consola? ¿La base de datos está en el mismo equipo donde corre la aplicación java (más que nada en le escenario web) o en otro? ¿Cuántos registros tiene la tabla? ¿Cada cuánto se actualiza? ¿Más de un usuario la puede actualizar? ¿Cuántos cálculos esperan realizar por unidad de tiempo?
A lo que voy, es no existe una verdad absoluta. Si escenarios donde una solución, resulta bajo cierto punto de vista, mejor que otra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin duda alguna es mejor tenerlo en el código, por las siguientes razones:

1. Un servidor de aplicaciones puede escalar tanto horizontal como verticalmente; mientras que la base de datos (relacionales, nosql es
   otro mundo), solo puede escalar verticalmente
2. Separar el repositorio de datos de la lógica de negocio, facilitará
   la labor de cambiar de engine en caso de ser necesario
3. Una función java/php/c#/etc, son más fáciles de depurar y proveen
   más y mejores herramientas para realizar un mejor trabajo
4. Normalmente, las funciones TSQL (más por "flojera" del programador
   que otra cosa) no quedan almacenadas en un motor de versionamiento; mientras que el código de aplicación usualmente sí

Ahora, recomendaría que fuera realizado en TSQL en los siguientes escenarios:

1. La aplicación solo tiene dos capas (BD y front end), y además la
   función requiere computo intensivo.
2. La función requiere un set de datos muy grandes para entregar un
   resultado. Por ejemplo, si la función calculará el promedio de 2
   millones de registros. Ahí, el ancho de banda de la red será un
   problema y se obtendrá una mejor performance implementarlo en TSQL

A modo de resumen, siempre implementa la lógica de negocio en la capa de negocio de la aplicación, y cambia de estrategia solo en escenarios que se justifiquen, como los señalados anteriormente.

Answer (score 1):

Usar TSQL.  No importa cual sea el indicador o la situación de desempeño, siempre sera mejor realizar lo máximo posible de desarrollo del lado de un servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Tal como dice @ElAsiduo, depende de cada caso, no suele haber verdades absolutas en nuestro campo. El rendimiento de las funciones dentro de la base de datos es mayor pero ¿y si mañana la aplicación necesita migrar a otra base de datos diferente? ¿O si la función se llama muchas veces por cada usuario?

Así que, dependiendo mucho del caso, será mejor en la BD o no.